# * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating script

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to run a new React native project on an Android emulator and i get this error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '...\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 213
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module '...\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}

please someone help, i trying to fix that for a long time.

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is referred to by community members as creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I did not write any code, this is a new React Nativ project with no change that I tried to run.